# Rolling Average for last 3 days

Tags: r, machine-learning

How to calculate rolling (avarage,maximum, minimum and sum) for last 3 days each of the caller, I have tried rolling average but did not get success, My sample data as follows:

```
  Day   Caller Total Call
   2      A       2
   7      B       1
   8      C       1
   9      A       1
  10      B       1
  11      C       2
  12      A       1
  13      B       1
  14      C       1
  15      A       2
  16      B       2
  17      C       1
  18      A       4
  19      B       4
  20      C       1
  21      A       1
  22      B       2
  23      C       1
  24      A       2
  25      B       1
```

So my expected result will be as follows:

```
 15      A       2     mean 1.33
```

since last 3 days A values are 1,1,2

Similary I would like to calculate sum,mean etc for caller A,B and C.

```
      # load packages
       require(data.table)
        require(zoo)
        callA <-as.data.table(callA)
        setkey(callA, "Caller", "Day")
        callA[, Rolling.Average := rollmean(Sum, 3, fill = NA), by = caller]
```

Thanks !!!  It works fine but it showed error  Error: k <= n is not TRUE  when    my data for looks like:

```
    Day   Caller Total Call                                                                                                                    
    2   1.16E+11        1
    2   1.19E+11        2
    2   662026601483    1
   2    772221884003    1
   2    442424243639    1
   2    345503159325    2
   2    5632504865891   2
   2    45672507410322  1                                                                                       Any solution for the same, I feel my Caller variable have some problem, I have converted to caller variable as character still it showed error 
  Error: k <= n is not TRUE
```

Comment: Could you show  your code in R?

Comment: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/zoo/html/rollapply.html

Comment: # load packages
         require(data.table)
         require(zoo)
        callA <-as.data.table(callA)
        setkey(callA, "Caller", "Day")
        callA[, Rolling.Average := rollmean(Sum, 3, fill = NA), by = caller]

Comment: code added as you mentioned but it showed error data.table gives the error Error: k <= n is not TRUE

Comment: Last 3 values for `A` are 2, 1 and 4 and looking at your example, I feel you just need `mean` and `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

We can `group_by` `Caller` and select last three rows for every group usinig `tail` and calculate its `sum` and `mean` respectively.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Caller) %>% 
   summarise(last_three_mean = mean(tail(Total_Call, 3)), 
             last_three_sum = sum(tail(Total_Call, 3)))


#    Caller last_three_mean last_three_sum
#    <fctr>        <dbl>       <int>
#1      A       2.333333           7
#2      B       2.333333           7
#3      C       1.000000           3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the index right-aligned instead of centered? In that case try

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
callA <- fread("Day   Caller TotalCall
   2      A       2
   7      B       1
   8      C       1
   9      A       1
  10      B       1
  11      C       2
  12      A       1
  13      B       1
  14      C       1
  15      A       2
  16      B       2
  17      C       1
  18      A       4
  19      B       4
  20      C       1
  21      A       1
  22      B       2
  23      C       1
  24      A       2
  25      B       1")
setkey(callA, "Caller", "Day")
callA[, Rolling.Average := rollmeanr(TotalCall, 3, fill = NA), by = Caller]
callA
#     Day Caller TotalCall Rolling.Average
#  1:   2      A         2              NA
#  2:   9      A         1              NA
#  3:  12      A         1        1.333333
#  4:  15      A         2        1.333333 # <====
#  5:  18      A         4        2.333333
#  6:  21      A         1        2.333333
#  7:  24      A         2        2.333333
#  8:   7      B         1              NA
#  9:  10      B         1              NA
# 10:  13      B         1        1.000000
# 11:  16      B         2        1.333333
# 12:  19      B         4        2.333333
# 13:  22      B         2        2.666667
# 14:  25      B         1        2.333333
# 15:   8      C         1              NA
# 16:  11      C         2              NA
# 17:  14      C         1        1.333333
# 18:  17      C         1        1.333333
# 19:  20      C         1        1.000000
# 20:  23      C         1        1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks !!!  It works fine but it showed error  Error: k <= n is not TRUE  when my data for looks like                                                                                        2 1.15E+11 1
2 1.16E+11 1
2 1.19E+11 2
2 662026601483 1
2 772221884003 1
2 442424243639 1
2 345503159325 2
2 5632504865891 2
2 45672507410322 1                                                                                      Any solution for the same, I feel my Caller variable have some problem,

Comment: Just by looking at the error message I'd assume that the number of data points per group is not greater or equal the window size 3. So one solution might be to exclude groups with less than 3 values.